# Why doesn't git-svn respect my $PATH?

Tags: git, path, homebrew, git-svn

I have installed `git` and `svn` with homebrew on my mac running 10.7.4. There are two versions of svn on my machine and I have set up my path to check for homebrew things first. Unfortunately git is using the wrong version of svn, so either it installed it's own version somewhere else, or it is ignoring my path.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)

$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.10.4 (svn 1.6.17)

$ /usr/bin/svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)

$ which git svn
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/svn

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I have looked briefly at git-svn.pl, unfortunately I don't know perl and I couldn't determine if the path was being set in there. So, why doesn't git use my path and how can I make it use the version of svn I need?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git svn` is not using your `$PATH` at all. It's using `$SVN::Core::VERSION`, as you can see in git-svn.perl, ll. 408 - 412 in `git version 1.7.11.rc3`:

```
sub version {
        ::_req_svn();
        print "git-svn version $VERSION (svn $SVN::Core::VERSION)\n";
        exit 0;
}
```

Neither `/usr/local/bin/svn` nor `/usr/bin/svn` control this version. I was able to replicate your issue on OSX 10.7.4 and corrected it with via [the 'cpan' shell:](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

```
sudo cpan;   # sudo required on the mac for the subversion make
cpan[1]> install SVN::Core
```

Hit `Enter` at every prompt and keep the defaults. It'll take a while, and might require installing some dependencies. My local had everything I needed but I have an unhealthy number of random libraries installed. Type `exit` or `Ctrl+C` after it finishes compilation. Now try `git svn --version`:

```
$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.11.rc3.5.g2ae48a9 (svn 1.7.3)
```